# copy assignment of std::vector member of a derived class causes memory leak when used in a polymorphic way

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, stdvector

in the following code I want to store an `input` `vector<double>` in the `derived` class.
I do so by applying a copy assignment of `std::vector` as a vector is passed to the `setIT` function.
I need it to use compute, which is implemented in derived.
A memory leak arises during this copy assignment.

This leak can be avoided by using: `vector<double> * input` instead of `vector<double> input`, but I do not understand why.

Can anyone clarify this? Thanks in advance.

```
#include "utilities.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace astro;

class base
{
  public:
    base () { cout<<" in base default constructor "<<endl; }
    virtual void setIT (void *v) = 0;
    virtual double compute () = 0;
};

class derived : public base
{
  protected:
    vector<double> input;

  public:
    derived ();
    virtual void setIT (void *v);
    virtual double compute () { /* using input vector to return something */ return 0; }
};

derived::derived () : base()
{
    cout<<" in derived default constructor "<<endl;
    input.resize(0);
}

void derived::setIT (void *v)
{
  cout<<" in derived setIT "<<endl;
  vector<double> * a = reinterpret_cast<vector<double>* >(v);
  input = *a;
  for (uint i = 0; i<input.size(); i++)
    cout<<i<<" "<<input[i]<<endl;
}

int main ()
{
  vector<double> test;
  fill_linear(test,5,1.,6.); // linear filling of test vector by '5' values between 1 and 6

  base * t = new derived;
  t->setIT (&test);
  cout<<t->compute()<<endl;

  delete t;
  t = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

the OUTPUT:

```
 in base default constructor 
 in derived default constructor 
 in derived setIT 
0 1
1 2.25
2 3.5
3 4.75
4 6
1
```

Comment: What evidence of the "memory leak" do you have?

Comment: Hmmm very smelly code... Why do you think there is a leak during assignment? There is a leak when you delete the base pointer. PS You probably don't want to be using `reinterpret_cast` yet.

Comment: @Angew using valgrind i found definetly lost bytes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually your program invokes undefined-behavior.

The destructor of the `base` class **must** be `virtual` in order to be well-defined.

Just define the destructor as:

```
virtual ~base() {}
```

Do this even if it is empty!

For detail, read this:

- [When should my destructor be virtual?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-dtors.html)

Comment: @CaptainMurphy: Thanks for the link. Added that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Of course the clean up only worked for the base, not for the derived class.

Comment: @Nawaz it compiled and ran such that no memory leaks were found by valgrind

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using void pointers in C++. If you want to handle different types, use templates instead.

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base(){}
  virtual double compute() const=0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{
private:
  std::vector<T> m_input;
public:
  void set_it(const T& in)
  {
    m_input = in;
  }
  double compute() const{/*Do the computation and return*/;}
};
```

Comment: I actually use void pointers, to deal with arbitrary kind of input, as further derived class will need different kinds of input (maybe a struct or strings)

Comment: I still fail to see how templates does not solve this. Maybe you have a special use case that really motivates void-pointers. It looks like your derived class has to know what types it expects since you cast to a specific type in the method. This will be handled with the templated class. And the compiler can check what you are doing.